# How to automate Flex application using UFT 12.54 in chrome?

Tags: apache-flex, hp-uft

I want to automate a Flex 4.5 application using 12.54 on chrome.  Through search engine results I tried installing "Flash Player Debugger V.28"

The issue is that the UFT is not able to identify objects in the Flex application. All objects are identified as "Webelement" with no unique properties. When I try to highlight the object entire web page is highlighted.